# Is there a way to make two way HorizontalPager with auto scroll?

Tags: kotlin, horizontal-scrolling, android-jetpack-compose

The HorizontalPager from [accompanist library](https://google.github.io/accompanist/api/pager/pager/com.google.accompanist.pager/-horizontal-pager.html) does a job of creating a simple ViewPager; is there a way to swipe infinitely in both ends?

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun AutoScrollPagerHorizontal(d: List<Stem>?) {
    var data: MutableList<Stem> = d?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()

    if (data.isNullOrEmpty()) return
    val pageState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = data.size)
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pageState
    ) {
        Card(
            Modifier
                .height(240.dp)
                .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = rememberGlidePainter(
                    request = data[it].icon,
                ),
                contentDescription = data[it].title,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates the viewpager correctly, but does not scroll to 0th index after reaching the last index of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PointerInput helped in building the bi-directional Pager; below is the snippet that worked for me.

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectHorizontalDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consumeAllChanges()
                        when {
                            dragAmount < 0 -> {
                                coroutineScope.launch { /* right */
                                    if (pageState.currentPage == data.lastIndex) {
                                        pageState.animateScrollToPage(0)
                                    } else {
                                        pageState.animateScrollToPage(pageState.currentPage + 1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            dragAmount > 0 -> { /* left */
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    if (pageState.currentPage == 0) {
                                        pageState.animateScrollToPage(data.lastIndex)
                                    } else {
                                        pageState.animateScrollToPage(pageState.currentPage - 1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this snippet in the composable to auto scroll the pager:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState.currentPage) {
    launch {
        delay(3000)
        with(pagerState) {
            val target = if (currentPage < pageCount - 1) currentPage + 1 else 0

            animateScrollToPage(
                page = target,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The auto scroll part is okay, I am more concerned about the bi-directional style of the HorizontalPager; any idea how to proceed with that?

Comment: animationSpec in animateScrollToPage() is removed in the latest version of Accompanist Pager library. Is there any way to manually customise the scroll effect? The default scroll transition is quite fast, need to slow it down a bit, but seems like there is no way out.